# Geometrizing saturation construction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

**Edit**: My original question quickly got one close request, so I edited it to add some context and motivation.

Consider homogeneous polynomials $J_1,\dots,J_r\in k[\bar x]$. I want to construct a projective variety $X$ such that $\operatorname{Cox}(X) = (k[J_1,\dots,J_r]:(x_1)^\infty)_{k[\bar x]}$. The aim is to generalize Mukai's construction in [this paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Counterexample-to-Hilbert%27%27s-fourteenth-problem-for-Mukai/5e39fa2ead35bb565fe59620b352cf1438436b02), or Doran-Giansiracusa's outline in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0691), which is later used in [their work with Jensen](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0350).

Consider the map $F:\mathbb{A}^n_x\to\mathbb{A}^r_u$ such that $F(\bar x) = (J_1(\bar x),\dots,J_r(\bar x))$, corresponding to the ring map $F^*:k[u_1,\dots,u_r]\to k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ such that $u_i\mapsto J_i(\bar x)$.

The problem would be solved if I could find an ideal $I\subseteq k[u_1,\dots,u_r]$ such that
$$
P\in I^m\iff F^*(P)\in (x_1)^m
$$
for all $m\geq 1$. Indeed, in this case the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^r_{[u_1:\dots:u_r]}$ along $I$ does the trick.

For $m=1$ we can take the ideal $I$ of $\overline{F(V(x_1))}$, which gives us that $P\in I\iff F^* (P)\in (x_1)$, this is, $I = (F^* )^{-1} ((x_1))$. However, in general we only seem to have
$$
I^m=(F^* )^{-1}((x_1))^m\subseteq (F^* )^{-1}((x_1)^m).
$$
Mukai shows the equality holds for every $m\geq 1$ for the specific polynomials they consider. However, it is not clear to me what property of his polynomials makes this work.

Any help is appreciated.